# How to get an Epic span multiple sprints?

Tags: user-stories, jira, sprint, epics

While setting up my Jira's project, I struggle to make an Epic span multiple sprints.
In other words, I expect an Epic (a complete feature) to be associated to multiple sprints.

The idea is that I want some user stories relative to one specific epic to be postponed to some next sprints.

For instance:

**Epic**: Viewing meetings

**US-1**:
Given I'm authenticated
And there exist some scheduled meetings
Then I can view meetings.
**US-2**:
Given I'm authenticated
And there exist some scheduled meetings
Then I can view meetings filtering by title.

I expect US-1 to be part of sprint 1 and US-2 (touchier) to be part of sprint 2.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the Epic's user stories to different sprints according to your needs. And when you browse the Epic you can see how its issues are distributed. Like the below example.
[image]

Comment: May you show the screen of the Epic detail? Is it attached to just one sprint or several? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I figure it out. whenever you drag some US from Epic 1 to a further sprint, the epic isn't marked as associated to one specific sprint (as before) since it's now spanned across 2 sprints (indeed there's no "sprint" label in Epic detail any more). Not intuitive at all but it sounds to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to assign the relevant user stories to sprints--not to assign the epic to sprints.